# How to split the column string by slicing in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, split, slice

I have column which i need to to split by (_)delimiter.

Here is an example text "`PPPP_OVS_ARG_MBC_MM-Models_RTNT_Always-On_IG VID - VW - #1 Engagement _ FY21 _ Febrero _ 202102 _ Falta OP"`

I can split it using

```
df['Name'].str.rsplit("_", expand=True)[0]
df['Name'].str.rsplit("_", expand=True)[1]
df['Name'].str.rsplit("_", expand=True)[2]
df['Name'].str.rsplit("_", expand=True)[3]
```

after this I don't want to split, I just need to get the whole string

```
"MM-Models_RTNT_Always-On_IG VID - VW - #1 Engagement _ FY21 _ Febrero _ 202102 _ Falta OP"
```

.. is there any way to slice it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `str.split(series,expand=True)` and `join`

```
print(df)


              Name
0       PPPP_OVS_ARG_MBC_MM-Models_RTNT_Always-On...
1       PPPP_OVS_ARG_MBC_MM-Models_RTNT_Always-On...
```

---

```
s = df['Name'].str.split('_',expand=True)


df1 = df.join(
    s.iloc[:,:3].join(
        s.iloc[:,3:].agg('_'.join,axis=1).to_frame('string')
            )
        )
```

---

```
print(df1)
```

[image]

#### edit to grab the last value.

```
df['last_value'] = df['Name'].str.split('_',expand=True).iloc[:,3]
```

Comment: Thanks but i need only the last value in a separate column

Comment: @s_khan92 it is in a seperate column called `string` ?

Comment: but its creating other extra columns 0,1,2 etc

Comment: Cool. Now its perfect but without last semicolon `df['last_value'] = df['Name'].str.split('_',expand=True).iloc[:,3]`

Comment: @s_khan92 thanks i didn't test it, sorry for my kurt response earlier but please do read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, actually i was in hurry and didn't able to add the expected output

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this.

```
df['Name'].str.split("_", 4)
```

That will return a list like this.

```
[PPPP, OVS, ARG, MBC, MM-Models_RTNT_Always-On_IG VID - VW - #1 Engagement _ FY21 _ Febrero _ 202102 _ Falta OP]
```

Comment: Thanks but i need only the last value in a separate column

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
df['New Column'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_', 4)[-1])
```